# The view mainsite.views.winner_detail didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Guys I'm losing my freaking mind.

I Keep getting this error after updating a model form.

I've made many of these forms before in previous projects and before and never had this issue.
I've looked at every single question here with the same issue and got nowhere.

this is the view

```
def winner_edit_form(request, pk):
winner = PrizeWinner.objects.get(id=pk)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = WinnerForm(request.POST, instance=winner)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('winner-details.html', winner.id)
else:
    form = WinnerForm(instance=winner)
    return render(request,'edit-winner-form.html',{'form': form})
```

I've tried several versions of this, including:

```
def winner_edit_form(request, pk):
if request.method == 'POST':
    winner = PrizeWinner.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = WinnerForm(request.POST or None, instance=winner)
    if form.is_valid() and request.POST['winner'] != '':
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('winner-detail')
else:
    form = WinnerForm(instance=winner)

context = {'winner': winner, 'form': form}
return render(request, 'partials/edit-winner-form.html', context)
```

I literally copied and pasted from previous and more complex projects and from other examples and I keep getting this error.

These are my urls

```
from django.urls import path
from mainsite import views

urlpatterns = [
      path('',views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),

      path("winner-detail/<int:pk>", views.winner_detail, name='winner-detail'),
      path("winner-detail/<int:pk>/edit/", views.winner_edit_form, name='winner_edit_form'),
  ]
```

models.py

```
class PrizeWinner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank= False)
    prizecode = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    prizestatus = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Unclaimed')
    prizechoices = models.CharField(max_length=200, null= True, blank= True, choices =PRIZE_CHOICES, default='£10 Bar Tab')
    date_won = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def pre_save_prize_code(instance, sender, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.prizecode:
        instance.prizecode= unique_prize_code_generator(instance)
    
pre_save.connect(pre_save_prize_code, sender= PrizeWinner)
```

This is my form

```
from django import forms
from mainsite.models import PrizeWinner

class WinnerForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = PrizeWinner
    fields =('name','prizestatus','prizechoices','comment')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without even reading the code I know two things. (1) You are falling off the end of the view function without returning a response object, and (2) you would be far better abandoning FBVs and using Class-based views.

OK, looking for the bug  now ...

Yes, with the first version if `form.is_valid()` returns False, no further code is executed and it returns None by default.

The second version ought not to be failing this way, though. Try it again? Some other error?

A CBV equivalent. Off the top of my head so it may contain bugs.

```
class WinnerEditView( UpdateView):
    template_name = 'partials/edit-winner-form.html'
    context_object_name = 'winner'
    model = PrizeWinner
    form_class = WinnerForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('winner_detail') # needs an app name?

    def form_valid( self, form):
        if request.POST['winner'] != '':  # I don't understand this, isn't the parsed pk the winner by definition?
            form.save()
```

url

```
path("winner-detail/<int:pk>/edit/", views.WinnerEditView.as_view(), name='winner_edit_form')
```